# How to configure Eclipse CDT to auto build & run on file save?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, configure

How to configure Eclipse CDT to auto build & run on file save?

> Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (includes Incubating components)
>
> Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same, configure to auto build on launch and auto save on build. So, to get a single click to save, build and run, use the launch button rather than the save button when configured as shown.

Eclipse > Window > Preferences
Run/Debug > Launching [image: Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching]